# how to change the displayed name of Wired ethernet in nm-applet

Tags: network-manager, ethernet, rename, wired

I just want to change the name shown in this picture (the name in the applet shown by red color) :

[click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hsEX.png)

NOT the name (vmnet1) that is shown in the ifconfig or IP link:

```
vmnet1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 172.12.222.1  netmask 255.255.254.0  broadcast 172.16.211.255
    inet6 fe80::250:43ff:fec0:1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:50:36:d0:00:02  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 402  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I have searched a lot in applet setting and nm settings from the GUI but there is no option to do so.

how can I do this?
thanks a lot.

Comment: Close-voters see comments under the answer, this is a Mint question.

Answer (score 2):

In `terminal`...

`cd /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` # change directory

`grep -i Realtek *` # find a text string

Note the filename that grep finds.

If the name is real long, rename the file...

`sudo mv current_file_name new_file_name` # rename the file, if required

Then edit the file and change the `id=` line to the name that you'd like...

`id=Wired Connection`

Reboot the system and check the network menu.

Comment: I have looked in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections before and the connection that is in the image isn't even there to edit. the command: " grep -i Realtek * " finds nothing in that path cuz there is no such file. except for the current internet device that I am connected to.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: im using mint 19 so ubuntu 18.04 in the core.

Comment: Technically Mint isn't supported here, as this is a Ubuntu site... however... edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `ifconfig`.

Comment: Are you using netplan? If so, show me the name/content of any .yaml files in /etc/netplan, and /etc/network/interfaces, and /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf.

Comment: sry to be late, I have added the requested items.

Comment: Everything looks normal. You may have to go to a Mint support site for more help, as I'm out of ideas for you.